# show postgresql database schema

Tags: postgresql

I want to show something like this with PostgreSQL but I don't know what I must searching for

[image]

can you explain to me how to show something like this with PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 3):

The image you shared is a graphical layout of tables.  PostgreSQL doesn't produce such output, but you can get the layout of individual tables by running `\d <tablename>` in psql.  This will provide you with the list of columns, column types, constraints, primary key, foreign keys and comments.

For example:

```
postgres=# \d catalogue
                               Table "public.catalogue"
   Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                Default
-------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id          | integer |           | not null | nextval('catalogue_id_seq'::regclass)
 item        | name    |           |          |
 qty         | integer |           |          |
 description | text    |           |          |
Indexes:
    "catalogue_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Alternatively, if you require a GUI-based solution, check out PgAdmin: https://www.pgadmin.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) for this,  using **View Diagram** option clicking in you schema

Comment: Thank you for your very constructive suggestion .